# NHD HR Dataset looks corrupt when I query intermittent and ephemeral streams

Tags: arcgis-pro, nhd

[image: NHD, Smiling at me]

I am trying to create a dataset for dry stream observations using NHD HR Dataset. But when I select only the streams with Feature Code "Intermittent" or "Ephemeral" it returns a very unnatural looking result. I tried using both NHD HR direct download and NHD HR dataset on ArcGIS portal.

Would this suggest an error on the dataset part?

Comment: Please provide the download link.

Comment: I'm guessing that all of the data is there, ArcPro just isn't rendering it correctly.  If try and select from the blank area, does it show selected records in the attribute table?

Comment: Thanks for your replies.
This is the direct link to the GDB from USGS
https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/StagedProducts/Hydrography/NHDPlusHR/Beta/GDB/NHDPLUS_H_0801_HU4_GDB.zip

I tried selecting as suggested, empty areas do not select the data (I'm checking with attribute table)

Comment: How much Memory do you have on your PC?

Comment: I have 32 GB ECC RAM on my desktop tied to a Xeon CPU and 8 GB on the laptop with an i5 CPU. It looks the same on both systems using ArcGIS 2.9.2 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest clearing your cache. It appears to be a rendering issue as stated above.

Comment: Thank you, this looks the same on multiple computers and multiple GIS software. Have you tried looking at it? We just accepted it as it is, I think they are categorizing these streams in grids and the empty ones are not categorized, yet.